# Count Groups of Objects in List

Tags: java

I have a list of objects and need to count the number of objects that have the same date, location and color in Java 8:

```
public class Entity

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     List<Schedule> schedule = new ArrayList<Scheudle>();
     schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Red", "Bob"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Red", "Jimmy"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Red", "Tim"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Blue", "Mary"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Green", "Jane"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Green", "Jane"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("13/12/2021", "San Deigo", "Red", "Bob"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("13/12/2021", "San Deigo", "Green", "James"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("13/12/2021", "San Deigo", "Green", "Anne"));
     schedule.add(new Schedule("14/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Red", "James"));
}
```

So for the above the totals would be for the number of people working each combination of date, location and color. i.e.:

- 12/12/2021 Los Angeles Red - 3
- 12/12/2021 Los Angeles Blue - 1
- 12/12/2021 Los Angeles Green - 2
- 13/12/2021 San Deigo Green - 2
- 13/12/2021 San Deigo Red - 1
- 14/12/2021 Los Angeles Red - 1

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If that is what you *need*, then I suggest you get started coding it.

Comment: Specify how the many existing Questions and Answers on grouping objects have not addressed your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on the three fields `date`, `location`, and `color`:

```
schedule.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Schedule::getDate,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Schedule::getCity,
            Collectors.groupingBy(Schedule::getColor,
                Collectors.counting()
            )
        )
    )
)
```

It generates the nested `Map`:

```
{
    14/12/2021={
        Los Angeles={Red=1}
    },
    13/12/2021={
        San Deigo={Red=1, Green=2}
    },
    12/12/2021={
        Los Angeles={Red=3, Blue=1, Green=2}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
record Schedule(String date, String location, String color, String name) {}
List<Schedule> schedule = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Red", "Bob"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Red", "Jimmy"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Red", "Tim"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Blue", "Mary"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Green", "Jane"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("12/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Green", "Jane"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("13/12/2021", "San Deigo", "Red", "Bob"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("13/12/2021", "San Deigo", "Green", "James"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("13/12/2021", "San Deigo", "Green", "Anne"));
schedule.add(new Schedule("14/12/2021", "Los Angeles", "Red", "James"));
record ScheduleGroup(String date, String location, String color) {}
Map<ScheduleGroup, Long> groups = schedule.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        s -> new ScheduleGroup(s.date(), s.location(), s.color()),
        Collectors.counting()));
for (Entry<ScheduleGroup, Long> g : groups.entrySet())
    System.out.println(g);
```

output:

```
ScheduleGroup[date=13/12/2021, location=San Deigo, color=Green]=2
ScheduleGroup[date=12/12/2021, location=Los Angeles, color=Blue]=1
ScheduleGroup[date=14/12/2021, location=Los Angeles, color=Red]=1
ScheduleGroup[date=13/12/2021, location=San Deigo, color=Red]=1
ScheduleGroup[date=12/12/2021, location=Los Angeles, color=Green]=2
ScheduleGroup[date=12/12/2021, location=Los Angeles, color=Red]=3
```

Comment: Since you're using streams and lambdas, stick with it: `groups.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: So you are creating a map, and then streaming the list in with a grouping?

Answer (score 0):

you can always make a list of a list ie an "adjacency list".
something like "ArrayList<ArrayList < String > >".